# Could not load content for webpack source file in Chrome sources tab

Tags: webpack, source-maps

I'm using webpack v4.16.2 as my bundle tool, and set `devtool` to `'source-map'`. I'm trying to debug the source file through the Chrome sources tab. However, when I click the source file lie down `webpack://` directory, an error occurred:

[image]

I'm not using `webpack-dev-server`, just build the source files into the `dist/` folder, and load the page through Nginx.

What does this error mean? I'm pretty sure that the source map files are generated. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

Alex is right,

> source-map devtool mode generate .map file when minify the code in production mode, file lost **sourcesContent** property.

Another way to fix it is to uncheck the `Enable JavaScript source maps` in Chrome Dev Tool.
[image: screenshot of Chrome Dev Tool settings]

Answer (score 0):

I have been the same issue this whole day:

try set webpack.prod.config

```
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
```

Here is what I found so far:

*source-map* devtool mode generate .map file lost **sourcesContent** property when minify the code which is default in **production** mode. And the 'webpack://XXXX' to locate the sourcesContent where the original code is, then the error happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting exactly the same problem, same error message etc when trying to debug typescript / html in Google Chrome.

The solution is to empty your cache.

Press Control + H to load up your browser history, and press the Clear Data button.

The try pressing Control + O or Control + P to load/select a source file again.

[image]